# Ajax send no data [ Codeigniter ]

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have a problem in ajax, indeed, i try to send value with ajax to my upload function before submit.
But when i check the $_POST array in my php code, there is only the value of the form, and not from the ajax, and I don't know why.
Here is my code :

**HTML:**

```
<button id="btn_saisie" class="btn btn-app saver adddocu" ><i class="fa fa-save whiter"></i></button>

<form action="/uploader/adddocu" id="form_saisie" class="form_saisie" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="document" class="val_peage form-control form_num" id="document" data-rest="document" placeholder="Document">
<input type="text" name="description" class="val_parking form-control form_num" id="description" data-rest="description" placeholder="Description">
```

**JS :**

```
$( ".adddocu" ).click(function() {
if ($('#document').val() != "" && $('#description').val() != ""){
    api_sendvalue_adddoc();
}
if ($('#document').val() == "")
    alert('test');
else if ($('#description').val() == "")
    alert('test2'); });


function api_sendvalue_adddoc(){
user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
pays = localStorage.getItem("pays");
magasin = localStorage.getItem("magasin");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/uploader/adddocu',
    data: {pays:pays, magasin:magasin},
    success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                $("#form_saisie").submit();
      console.log(data);
    },
            error: function(xhr){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
}); }
```

**PHP:**

```
public function adddocu(){
    $path = './asset/upload/pdf/';
    $path2 = '/asset/upload/pdf/';
    $config['upload_path']   = $path;
    $config['encrypt_name']   = false;
    $config['file_ext_tolower']  = true;
    $config['allowed_types']  = 'pdf';

    // die(var_dump($_POST));
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    foreach($_FILES as $id => $name)
    {
        $this->upload->do_upload('document');
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $url =  $path2 . $upload_data['file_name'];
        $data = array('nom' => $upload_data['raw_name'], 'description' => $_POST['description'], 'url' => $url, 'user_id' => '17');
        $this->db->insert('pdf', $data);
    }
    redirect("/login/docu");
}
```

So, when I var_dump the $_POST array, I only have the value of "description", and not of "pays" and "magasin".

Can you help me please?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess you are missing dataType : "json" while making an ajax call
ajax parameters should be like  type: 'POST',
    `url: '/uploader/adddocu',
    dataType : "json",
    data: {pays:pays, magasin:magasin},`

Comment: If I add datatype , the function doesn't work, and it call error

Comment: what error you are getting ?  make sure its  `dataType`  not `datatype`

Comment: It's dataType, and if i console log xhr in error function, i have this `Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "array(2) {↵  ["pays"]=>↵  string(2) "be"↵  ["magasin"]=>↵  string(2) "fn"↵}↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like  you are accessing localstorage value , you are posting it somewhere and then submiting the form.

More you are submiting the form which dont have this `pays` & `magasin` so i have a trick using which you can achieve it.

Create two hidden inputs inside your HTML form like

```
<input type="hidden" name="pays" id="pays">
<input type="hidden" name="magasin" id="magasin">
```

Now before ajax call give them values after getting it from local storage, like this.

```
user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
pays = localStorage.getItem("pays");
magasin = localStorage.getItem("magasin");

$("#pays").val(pays);
$("#magasin").val(magasin);

$.ajax({ .... });
```

Continue your code and enjoy. 
Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: I'm sure i'm getting pays and magasin because in success function i make `alert(data)` and i have the value.
With your code, nothing change, my $_POST don't have the ajax value

Comment: check in xhr call in network tab in your firebug if you are getting any error

Comment: did you try  like this ?   data : $( "#form_saisie" ).serialize(),

Comment: Yes, i tried this, and i add my value with data.push, it doesn't work

Comment: @CorentinVerpillat Please join this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122559/laravel-5-2-talk

Comment: I can't speak in this chat because I don't have 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are not preventing the `form` from being submit normally, so the AJAX request is cancelled. Instead of using the `click` event of the `button`, hook to the `submit` event of the `form` and call `preventDefault()`. Try this:

```
$('#form_saisie').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#document').val() != "" && $('#description').val() != ""){
        api_sendvalue_adddoc();
    }

    if ($('#document').val() == "")
        alert('test');
    else if ($('#description').val() == "")
        alert('test2'); 
});
```

Comment: I already try to make that, but when i do that, the submit have an infinite loop. 
And in my code, I don't have to prevent the submit button because of, it's not a submit button, it's only a button, and when I click, i make the submit in ajax>

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Here is a working example of a ajax post to codeigniter:

**View**

```
<script> 
    $( document ).ready(function () {
      // set an on click on the button
      $("#button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "[page]",
              data: {pays: "asd", magasin: "dsa"},
              success: function(data){
                          alert(data);
                          $("#text").html(data);
                       console.log(data);
              },
                      error: function(xhr){
                          alert(xhr.responseText);
                          console.log(xhr.responseText);
                      }
          });

      });
    });
  </script>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
    // main ajax back end
    class Time extends CI_Controller {
        // just returns time
        public function index()
        {
            var_dump($_POST);
            echo time();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["pays"]=>
  string(3) "asd"
  ["magasin"]=>
  string(3) "dsa"
}
1473087963
```

[Working example here](http://code.runnable.com/V82LjIRiC9tf0Ls-/ajax-post-snippet-for-codeigniter-and-php)

So you should check the request that you're making from AJAX, on dev console. There you should get the response with the var_dump($_POST).

to debug try to make your controller return only the $_POST data, comment the rest. and same thing on javascript side, test only the ajax post and data received.